# How to simplify/optimize this union statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code that I wrote for for a query that the client needed. The results gives me exactly what we need, however i am getting some really long response times. The first part of thequery takes longer than the second, when the query itself its not very much different. Basically they are two different queries that I combined into one using UNION ALL.

Any feedback would be great to simplify this.
thanks

```
Select * from
(

Select b.Storage_Loc_Nbr as locNbr, b.CurrentLoadCount,b.MMM_Id_Nbr,
(SELECT count(Load_ID) as LoadCount 
    FROM t_load c
    WHERE b.MMM_Id_Nbr=c.MMM_Id_Nbr
    and
    QC_Status_Code like 'R%' and mmm_Facility_Code ='MC' and     Active_Status_Ind='A'
    and
    b.Storage_Loc_Nbr <> c.Storage_Loc_Nbr)as OtherLocCount

    FROM
(

SELECT * FROM

(

    SELECT t_load.Storage_Loc_Nbr, 
    Count(t_Load.Load_Id) AS CurrentLoadCount,
    t_load.MMM_Id_Nbr,
    t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Type_Code

    FROM t_Load LEFT JOIN t_Storage_Location ON t_Load.Storage_Loc_Nbr = t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr
    WHERE (

    ((t_load.MMM_Id_Nbr) between '702004%' and '702011%')
    AND ((t_Load.Active_Status_Ind)='A')
    AND ((t_Load.QC_Status_Code) Like 'R%') 
    AND ((t_Load.MMM_Facility_Code)='MC')
    AND  ((t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Type_Code)='CD')
)

    GROUP BY t_load.MMM_Id_Nbr,
    t_load.Storage_Loc_Nbr,
    t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Type_Code

 HAVING
    Count(t_Load.Load_Id)<=1




    )
    as a

)  
as b


)
as c
Group By
locNbr,CurrentLoadCount, MMM_Id_Nbr, OtherLocCount
having OtherLocCount>0

UNION ALL

Select * from
(

Select b.Storage_Loc_Nbr as locNbr, b.CurrentLoadCount,b.MMM_Id_Nbr,
(SELECT count(Load_ID) as LoadCount 
    FROM t_load c
    WHERE b.MMM_Id_Nbr=c.MMM_Id_Nbr
    and
    QC_Status_Code like 'R%' and mmm_Facility_Code ='MC' and Active_Status_Ind='A'
    and
    b.Storage_Loc_Nbr <> c.Storage_Loc_Nbr)as OtherLocCount

 FROM
(

SELECT * FROM

(

    SELECT t_load.Storage_Loc_Nbr, 
    Count(t_Load.Load_Id) AS CurrentLoadCount,
    t_load.MMM_Id_Nbr,
    t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Type_Code

    FROM t_Load LEFT JOIN t_Storage_Location ON t_Load.Storage_Loc_Nbr = t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr
    WHERE (

    ((t_load.MMM_Id_Nbr) between '702004%' and '702011%')
    AND ((t_Load.Active_Status_Ind)='A')
    AND ((t_Load.QC_Status_Code) Like 'R%') 
    AND ((t_Load.MMM_Facility_Code)='MC')
    AND  ((t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Type_Code)<>'CD') AND
    ((t_load.Storage_Loc_Nbr)<>'clc' AND (t_load.Storage_Loc_Nbr)<>'WHLEAD')    AND
(
((t_load.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%A') 
OR((t_load.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%B')
OR ((t_load.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%C') 
OR ((t_load.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%D') 
OR ((t_load.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%E'))
)

    GROUP BY t_load.MMM_Id_Nbr,
    t_load.Storage_Loc_Nbr,
    t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Type_Code



    HAVING
    Count(t_Load.Load_Id)<=1



    )
    as a

)  
as b


)
as c
Group By
locNbr,CurrentLoadCount, MMM_Id_Nbr, OtherLocCount
having OtherLocCount>0
Order by
LocNbr
```

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan to see where the bottlenecks are?  Using `LIKE` patterns that start with a wildcard prevent indexed access, but may still benefit from an index.  (A full scan of an index may be much faster than a table scan.)  Is anything indexed?

Comment: @HABO +1. OP have you tried using a SQL Profiler?

Answer (score 1):

I've only looked at the first part of the union

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72b6d/9/0 is very similar to the original query, with some minor simplifications that the optimizer would probably do itself.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72b6d/11/0 produces the same results with the test data I've written. Feel free to extend this with something more representative. It uses CTEs (copied below)

```
-- CTE Version
With T As (
Select
  l.Storage_Loc_Nbr,
  l.MMM_Id_Nbr,
  Count(Load_ID) As LoadCount
From 
  t_load l
Where
  l.QC_Status_Code like 'R%' And
  l.mmm_Facility_Code ='MC' And
  l.Active_Status_Ind='A' And
  l.MMM_Id_Nbr between '702004%' and '702011%'
Group By
  l.Storage_Loc_Nbr,
  l.MMM_Id_Nbr
)

Select
  t1.Storage_Loc_Nbr LocNbr,
  t1.LoadCount CurrentLoadCount,
  t1.MMM_Id_Nbr,
  t2.TotalCount - t1.LoadCount OtherLocCount
From
  T t1
    Inner Join (
      Select
        MMM_Id_Nbr,
        Sum(LoadCount) TotalCount
      From
        T  
      Group By
        MMM_Id_Nbr
    ) t2
    On t1.MMM_Id_Nbr = t2.MMM_Id_Nbr
    Left Outer Join
  t_Storage_Location sl
    On t1.Storage_Loc_Nbr = sl.Storage_Loc_Nbr
Where
  sl.Storage_Loc_Type_Code = 'CD' and
  t1.LoadCount <= 1 And
  t2.TotalCount - t1.LoadCount > 0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72b6d/6/0 is another version that uses window functions as well as a gratuitous CTE:

```
-- Window Function Version
With T As (
Select
  l.MMM_Id_Nbr,
  l.Storage_Loc_Nbr,
  Count(Load_ID) Over (Partition By MMM_ID_Nbr, Storage_Loc_Nbr) As LoadCount,
  Count(Load_ID) Over (Partition By MMM_ID_Nbr) As TotalCount
From 
  t_load l
Where
  QC_Status_Code like 'R%' And
  mmm_Facility_Code ='MC' And
  Active_Status_Ind='A' And
  l.MMM_Id_Nbr between '702004%' and '702011%'
)

Select
  t1.Storage_Loc_Nbr LocNbr,
  t1.LoadCount CurrentLoadCount,
  t1.MMM_Id_Nbr,
  t1.TotalCount - t1.LoadCount OtherLocCount
From
  T t1
    Left Outer Join
  t_Storage_Location sl
    On t1.Storage_Loc_Nbr = sl.Storage_Loc_Nbr
Where
  sl.Storage_Loc_Type_Code = 'CD' and
  t1.LoadCount <= 1 And
  t1.TotalCount - t1.LoadCount > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT count(Load_ID) as LoadCount  
    FROM t_load c 
    WHERE b.MMM_Id_Nbr=c.MMM_Id_Nbr 
    and 
    QC_Status_Code like 'R%' and mmm_Facility_Code ='MC' and     Active_Status_Ind='A' 
    and 
    b.Storage_Loc_Nbr <> c.Storage_Loc_Nbr)as OtherLocCount
```

This is a correlated subquery. That means it runs row-by row. This is a programming technique that you should avoid using. Make it into a derived table instead.

Comment: i can't make a derived table in the production environment..:(

Comment: Of course you can. it i s part of teh query not a real table. Please google derived table.

Comment: can you write some samples how to create a CTE (or derived table) baSed on my query?